# Updating play-services gives repeated resources error

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, google-play-services

I want to use the new Google Cloud Messaging's `InstanceID` from Google Play Services, and for that I need to update my play-services library.
This is my dependencies from `build.dragle` from the current version:

```
dependencies {
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.1.+'

compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.+'
compile project(':slidingMenuLibrary')
compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.6'
compile 'com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0@aar'
compile files('libs/GraphView-3.1.1.jar')
compile files('libs/ksoap2-android-assembly-3.3.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar')
compile files('libs/libphonenumber-7.0.1.jar')
compile files('libs/opencsv-2.4.jar')
compile files('libs/ormlite-android-4.46.jar')
compile files('libs/ormlite-core-4.46.jar')
compile files('libs/ormlite-jdbc-4.46.jar')
}
```

And heres is `build.dragle` from slidingMenuLibrary:

```
dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.+'
compile 'com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0@aar'
}
```

I updated my Google Play Services on Android SDK Manager to the last version. But when I change `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.1.+'` to `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0'`, Android Studio give a list of errors:

```
Error:(1) Attribute "titleTextStyle" has already been defined
C:\Users\Rui\AndroidStudioProjects\tk-main-    repository\tkAndroid\src\main\res\values\colors.xml
Error:(1) Attribute "subtitleTextStyle" has already been defined
Error:(1) Attribute "divider" has already been defined
Error:(1) Attribute "background" has already been defined
Error:(1) Attribute "backgroundSplit" has already been defined
...
```

When I change back to `play-services:6.1.+'`, all errors disappear.
I know that I have repeated attributes, but I can't understand where can I change them, or what to do to solve this...

any sugestions?

Comment: I notice that in your `build.gradle` file, you compiled one of project `compile project(':slidingMenuLibrary')`, it might multi defined all the repeat things.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment... sorry I forgot to put the dependencies from slidingMenuLibrary also... I edited the question with that information... 

I discover that is the actionBarSherlock that is causing the duplicated elements... the problem is that I don't know how to remove those repeated elements from one of them...

any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is no longer recommended to use the full play-services dependency. Rather you should use the individual dependency that you require.

For GCM use:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.1.0'
```

See Table 1 in [this document](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#add_google_play_services_to_your_project) for the full list.

Comment: Thanks, this solve my problem...

please, just correct the above `compile` line to `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.1.0'`